# Can I kill the Fuzzies?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

Fuzzies are usually found on bouncy ropes or on transparent grids that they float along. They are incredibly annoying. I know that you cannot jump on them to kill them, or use Boomerang Mario, but is there any way you can get rid of them? Or are you just stuck with them?

A picture, for reference: [image: Fuzzy]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only method to kill fuzzies is to run into them while invincible due to the effects of a star.

Comment: You can probably kill them with statue mario as well, but I am uncertain.

Comment: I just tested it, you can **not** kill them with statue mario.

Comment: Thank for checking! It's too bad that is the only way :(

Comment: Can't you kill them with fire? Or a koopa shell?

Comment: @JasonChen: It's been a while since I played the game, but I'm fairly certain I tested this and you can't kill them with fire or koopa shells. The [mario wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/Fuzzy#Super_Mario_3D_Land) suggests this as well.

Comment: @Wipqozn Even if you there is a level with Koopas and Fuzzies, you can't carry or throw shells in this game, so it would be difficult or impossible to get them to collide.

Comment: Does touching them on the gamepad or shouting into the mic have any effect?  This usually doesn't kill enemies, but it sometimes freezes them making them easier to deal with.